# Training Day, the meaning of that snail story

Tags: plot-explanation, training-day

In the movie *Training Day*, Detective Alonzo Harris (Denzel Washington) took the rookie officer Jake Hoyt (Ethan Hawke) to visit a drug trader under his protection.

The drug trader told the rookie a story, it went something like this:

- A guy sees a snail and throws that snail somewhere, and after a long time, the same snail manages to crawl back in front of the same guy, this guy says "what the fxxx is your problem?"

Is this story somehow related to the story line, or is it simply a silly story to toy with this rookie?

Comment: My memory's hazy - but wasn't it the snail who asked what the guy's problem was?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There were two points to that story, and both had to do with handling your business.

From the snail's perspective, when life hands you lemons you make lemonade.  Keep moving forward, keep persisting and eventually you can overcome everything.

From the man's perspective, make sure you finish what you start because it may come back to haunt you.

Comment: Thanks, the second point is really insightful. I have been thinking of this scene on and off for over a decade now.